# Multiple devices using one webapp / account - data-synchronisation

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, architecture

I have built a webapp, a diary app. Users can log in with accounts and create/edit their diaries. A user can be logged-in with multiple devices at the same time, so if he changes something, the other devices will show the change as fast as possible.

I'm using MySQL and PHP for the backend, Angularjs for the main parts of handling the data on the client-side. I am looking for the most efficient way to do this.

My solution is that the server saves for each action (edit content, order of diaries etc.) the time when the change took place. The devices will save locally (in JavaScript variables) the time when it updated the last data and send this time via AJAX to the server (interval, e.g. 3 seconds).

This will return only the action-code (so the identifier of the action) and the required data (e.g. new content, new order) of the changes since the last request (the sent time); now the client-side (the JavaScript and Angularjs) handles this type of action and updates the view.

Is there any other solution which is better than mine and not more complicated (which can be done with the same expenditure)?

Comment: An AJAX on a timer is a good start. However once you've got that working, you might want to look into web sockets (long polling). Stack Overflow itself uses them to push page updates nearly in real-time, and they are more efficient than AJAX calls, which nearly always come back empty.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting, I'm new to stackoverflow (as you can see on my reputation-score) and English isn't my mothertungue.

I will have a look at long polling. Any opinion to the other part of my system? - I'm using it in a former version of the app (unpublished) but I want to know other ways to achieve this, if possible.